# Wildfly Maven Plugin does not keep the Wildfly instance running in the background

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-maven-plugin

I have a continuous build job for a Maven Java Project and I need the built application to be deployed to a WildFly 21 instance at the end of the job, which must be kept up and running.

Since it's a Maven project, I'm planning on using WildFly Maven Plugin. I configured version 3.0.2.Final with Maven 3.6.3 on my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
            <jboss-home>${jboss.home}</jboss-home>
            <server-config>${jboss.ser.config}</server-config>
            <properties-file>${jboss.properties.file}</properties-file>
            <server-args>
                <server-arg>jboss.server.base.dir=${jboss.server.base.dir}</server-arg>
            </server-args>
            <java-opts>
                <java-opt>-Xmx2048m -Xms640m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</java-opt>
            </java-opts>
            <startup-timeout>240</startup-timeout>
            <timeout>240</timeout>
            <protocol>remoting</protocol>
            <force>true</force>
            <filename>${filename}</filename>
            <name>${warfile.name}</name>
            <checkPackaging>false</checkPackaging>
            <hostname>${jboss.hostname}</hostname>
            <port>${jboss.management.port}</port>
    </configuration>
```

When I do `mvn wildfly:start` or `mvn wildfly:run`, the WildFly instance starts Ok, application is available, but when the timeout value is reached, the Maven process exits and the WildFly process receives an OS signal to shutdown, then stopping the instance. What I wanted is the WildFly process to be kept running in the background after Maven exits.

From the plugin documentation, I read "*wildfly:start starts the application server and leaves the process running*", so I was guessing that at least the `start` goal would leave the Wildfly instance runing after exit. But that's not what I see. How can I use the plugin in order to start a WildFly instance and keep it running in the background after Maven exits?

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest to use [Codehaus Cargo plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html) instead.

Comment: The (mvn)`-X` flag might give little more insight (at the costs of a huge output) According to your description and complex environment (wildfly)`stdout` parameter is also interesting..

Comment: Do you have the management port set correctly? The plugin will use the management client to determine if it's running. If it cannot determine it's running, then it will kill the process.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks for the suggestion. Reading carefully the documentation, I don't think I can do with it what I'm trying to achieve. `cargo:start` "will automatically shut down the container as soon as the parent Maven instance quits" and `cargo:run` will "start a container and wait for the user to press CTRL + C to stop". So none of it's goals will keep the container running on the background and leave gracefully. 
Reading Cargo plugin documentation and assuming both plugins implementation concepts are similar, I guess that I can't achieve what I want with none of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin is doing exactly what it should do, as the scope of `mvn wildfly:start` is `Starts a standalone instance of WildFly Application Server. The purpose of this goal is to start a WildFly Application Server for testing during the maven lifecycle.` as stated on the homepage of the plugin, so they do mean that this was just for testing, it makes perfect sense that the application server is terminated when the shutdown goal is reached.

So I think for this case, you should have an instance of your application server (wildfly) up and running already, and then you do the continuous job with `mvn wildfly:deploy`, as you don't want your application server on other environments (like UAT or PROD) to just restart every time you do the deployment.

More detail here : https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Reading the documentation more carefully, I agree with you about the `wildfly:start` goal. On the other hand, I think that `wildfly:run` should be what I want. My main question right now, as it's not clear on the documentation, is if `run` starts the Wildfly instance and blocks, waiting for some external shutdown. (I cannot test `run` because I have an error on the Maven lifecycle phase assembly when executed through `run`). If this is the case, then what I want is not possible with this plugin.

Comment: My first approach was exactly `wildfly:deploy`, having the Wildfly instance started before the build job. But I noticed that after some successive deployments, WildFly throws an _Out of Memory_, even doing `wildfly:undeploy` before the `deploy`. I noticed that the memory allocated during the deployment is not deallocated on `undeploy` and doubles its size during the next `deploy`. I didn't understand if this is caused by a Wildfly 21 or my application memory leak.